# Using Azure AppService on Windows IoT

Tags: uwp, windowsiot

I am trying to develop an UWP app that runs on Windows IoT (Raspberry Pi 2) and serves requests from a UWP app that is running on a phone, desktop etc.

For the client/server communication, I am trying to use UWP AppService (or Project Rome). I was able to open a connection from the phone to my dev laptop but when I deploy the app to the IoT device, it is not found by the client app.

I think the reason is that the app on the IoT device is not associated with my Live Id (or MSA).

Does anybody know if this is a supported scenario e.g. if
1. I can define an MSA that is used in the app on the IoT device
2. If it is possible to use one app that serves requests to multiple accounts

Thanks,
Sebastian